# Dividing test data into k-mean cluster in matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have 525 datas which I have clustered into 2 parts using `kmeans` function. When I have a test data I want to put it accordingly into to a cluster. To do that I have to measure the distance of the test data and centroid of both clusters. Lowest distance means the data is on that cluster.

How do I do that?

PS: the data has 9 inputs which means each data consists of 9 values.

Here is what I have tried:

```
for n = 1:174
  for k = 1:9
  testclust1(n,k) = C(1,k)-TEST(n,k)
  testclust2(n,k) = C(2,k)-TEST(n,k)
end 
if testclust1(1,:) <= testclust2(1,:)
%then cluster 1 else cluster 2
end
```

Any idea about it?

Comment: Is this a pseudocode? or what? What are `C`, `TEST`, `testclust`?

Comment: Where is the distance function, the centeroid computation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pdist2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html):

```
 dist_to_centers = pdist2(C, TEST);
```

`dist_to_centers` is 2-by-174 matrix with the distance of each test point to the centers.

```
 idx_of_test_points_in_first = find(dist_to_centers(1,:)<=dist_to_centers(2,:)); 
 idx_of_test_points_in_second = find(dist_to_centers(1,:)>dist_to_centers(2,:));
```

If you want to manually compute `dist_to_centers` you can use [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun):

```
dist_to_centers = bsxfun(@minus, permute(C,[1 3 2]), permute(TEST,[3 1 2]));
dist_to_centers = sum( dist_to_centers.^2, 3 );
```